# Модель Объекта C++

Tags: c++, c++11

В **[черновике стандарта C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)** есть такой параграф **The C++ object model**
и там написано следующее:

**An object is created by a definition**, *[создается при определении объекта (понятно)]*

**by a new-expression**, *[создается с помощью new-expression (понятно)]*

**or by the implementation when needed.** *[что такое implementation when needed, и с чем его едят? ]*

ВОПРОС: Что такое implementation when needed, и с чем его едят?

Comment: Там есть ссылка на раздел [class.temporary]. В текущем черновике определение более подробное: [An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#:object_model). Тут "when a temporary object is created" соответствует старому "by the implementation when needed".

Comment: @cppquestions все же, говоря не абстрактно и лаконично, что это значит, в каких случаях это бывает? вы знаете? можете дать ответ?

Comment: там нужно дальше почитать. Например, если объект возвращается с функции (хотя там сейчас есть материализация), когда нужно скопировать объект (при передаче параметра) и тому подобное

Comment: Тег `c++` лучше оставить. Обычно `c++??` вешают в дополнение к просто `c++`, потому что у последнего популярность больше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[В том же самом черновике стандарта C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) в разделе (как и было упомянуто в комментариях к вопросу от пользователя @cppquestions ) **12.2 Temporary objrcts**, 
дается разъяснения про временные объекты (как мы все уже поняли)!
И отвечая на вопрос как трактовать "**An object is created by the implementation when needed**", в каких случаях, где и как это происходит.

**Коротко** можно написать следующее:

1. binding a reference to a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) (8.5.3),
2. returning a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) (6.6.3),
3. a conversion that creates a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) (4.1, 5.2.9, 5.2.11, 5.4),
4. throwing an exception (15.1),
5. entering a handler (15.3),
6. and in some initializations (8.5).

Как можно было заметить, каждый пункт в свою очередь ссылается на разделы, где и даются более развернутые ответы, для каждого.